# How to define a global variable in WiX

Tags: wix

How do I to pass in a WiX variable defined in another file (without redefining it again)?

It seems like the standard way of defining a variable is this:

```
<?define Var1= "****" ?>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's right, you can define some variables in this syntax. Then include them in a separate WiX include file, with the extension `.wxi`. (like a `.h` include file), for example `MyWixDefines.wxi`. Then in your other WiX file *Fragments*, include this file, like this:

```
<?include MyWixDefines.wxi ?>
```

And finally, in the other fragments, you reference the variable like this:

```
<Icon Id="myIcon" SourceFile="$(var.Var1)\images\someicon.ico" />
```

A reminder: The variable is resolved at WiX *compile* time. It's not dynamically available at *install* time.